# Installing 'arima_utils' with conda

Tags: arima

can't find any tips how to install 'arima_utils'. Mentioned in "Practical ML with PYthon" from Sarkar, Bali & Sharma.

Comment: I look like you can find the answer there : https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

`arima_utils` has been developed by the authors of the book and is not a part of any standard library.

You can find it there : https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/tree/master/notebooks/Ch11_Forecasting_Stock_and_Commodity_Prices

Ref : https://github.com/dipanjanS/practical-machine-learning-with-python/issues/16